# Shift Columns in Pandas different columns length

Tags: python, pandas, shift

I have a table like the table below. It's the way it is because it's a csv without a quote character. So I have different a different number of columns for each row.

In my data I have two description fields that duplicate the problem. I tried filtering the data where Unnamed 1 is null and Unnamed 3 is not null I then concatenated description 1 and entered date with a comma. I was then going to shift the columns left. The only example I found shifted the whole table. Is there any way to just shift the data starting at a certain column?

I would then just shift more cells when there were 2 commas that need to be pushed to the description fields.

What I have:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "ID": ["001", "002", "003", "004", "005", "006"],
    "Amount": [4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5],
    "Descrption 1": ["Hi", "Good", "Biz", "S", "Okay", "Good2"],
    "Entered Date": ["Jill", "2021-01-02", "Money", "O", "Sarah", '2021-03-04'],
    "Description 2": ['2021-01-01', "Good", "Inc", "S", "2021-04-13", "Good2"],
    "Tax": ['Hi', .4, '2021-03-02', "2021-03-25", "Okay", .4],
    "Unnamed: 1": ["Jill", np.nan, "Biz", 'S', "Sarah", np.nan],
    "Unnamed: 2": [.4, np.nan, "Money", 'O', .7, np.nan],
    "Unnamed: 3": [np.nan, np.nan, "Inc", 'S', np.nan, np.nan],
    "Unnamed: 4": [np.nan, np.nan, .3, .2, np.nan, np.nan],})
```

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After your first text field, you have a column that looks like a date. Let’s first find where it is in each row:

```
>>> match_date = df2.select_dtypes('object').transform(
...      lambda s: s.str.match('20\d\d-\d\d-\d\d')
... ).reindex(columns=df2.columns).fillna(False)
>>> match_date.idxmax(axis='columns')
0    Description 2
1     Entered Date
2              Tax
3              Tax
4    Description 2
5     Entered Date
dtype: object
```

From there we can identify the columns that contain the first text field:

```
>>> after_found_date = match_date.cummax(axis='columns')
>>> df2.where(~after_found_date.loc[:, 'Descrption 1':])
    ID  Amount Descrption 1 Entered Date Description 2  Tax Unnamed: 1 Unnamed: 2 Unnamed: 3  Unnamed: 4
0  NaN     NaN           Hi         Jill           NaN  NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN         NaN
1  NaN     NaN         Good          NaN           NaN  NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN         NaN
2  NaN     NaN          Biz        Money           Inc  NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN         NaN
3  NaN     NaN            S            O             S  NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN         NaN
4  NaN     NaN         Okay        Sarah           NaN  NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN         NaN
5  NaN     NaN        Good2          NaN           NaN  NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN         NaN
```

So let’s reconstitute this field with `.agg()`, remove the bits that were all over the place with `.mask()`, and shift the other values to the left with `.transform()`:

```
>>> df2['Descrption 1'] = df2.where(~after_found_date.loc[:, 'Descrption 1':]).agg(
...     lambda s: s.str.cat(sep=','), axis='columns'
... )
>>> df2.loc[:, 'Entered Date':] = df2.mask(~after_found_date).loc[:, 'Entered Date':]
>>> df2 = df2.transform(lambda s: pd.Series(list(s.dropna().values) +
...                                         [np.nan] * s.isna().sum(), index=s.index),
...                     axis='columns')
>>> df2
    ID Amount   Descrption 1 Entered Date Description 2    Tax Unnamed: 1 Unnamed: 2 Unnamed: 3 Unnamed: 4
0  001      4        Hi,Jill   2021-01-01            Hi   Jill        0.4        NaN        NaN        NaN
1  002      1           Good   2021-01-02          Good    0.4        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
2  003      2  Biz,Money,Inc   2021-03-02           Biz  Money        Inc        0.3        NaN        NaN
3  004      2          S,O,S   2021-03-25             S      O          S        0.2        NaN        NaN
4  005      4     Okay,Sarah   2021-04-13          Okay  Sarah        0.7        NaN        NaN        NaN
5  006      5          Good2   2021-03-04         Good2    0.4        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
```

For the second description field, let’s d the same but a little easier as we know there’s just one field after it:

```
>>> df2['Description 2'] = df2.loc[:, 'Description 2':].agg(
...     lambda s: s.dropna().iloc[:-1].str.cat(sep=', '), axis='columns'
... )
>>> df2['Tax'] = df2.agg(lambda s: s.dropna().iloc[-1], axis='columns')
>>> df2.drop(columns=df2.columns[df2.columns.str.startswith('Unnamed: ')])
    ID Amount   Descrption 1 Entered Date    Description 2  Tax
0  001      4        Hi,Jill   2021-01-01         Hi, Jill  0.4
1  002      1           Good   2021-01-02             Good  0.4
2  003      2  Biz,Money,Inc   2021-03-02  Biz, Money, Inc  0.3
3  004      2          S,O,S   2021-03-25          S, O, S  0.2
4  005      4     Okay,Sarah   2021-04-13      Okay, Sarah  0.7
5  006      5          Good2   2021-03-04            Good2  0.4
```